# sprintf not entering info into database

Tags: printf

Wondering if someone can help figure out why this code is not entering all info into database. it only enters an id, newuser_id and a siteid after coming back from paypal. It refuses to enter anything else.
Is there any code to replace this sprint crap? I don't know what else to do or try or how to test where it fails.

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO turnkeys_paypal_data values(NULL,\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',%d,\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',%0.2f,%d,%d,%d)', 
$_POST['address_status'], 
$_POST['payer_id'], 
$_POST['address_street'], 
$_POST['payment_date'], 
$_POST['address_zip'], 
$_POST['first_name'], 
$_POST['address_country'], 
$_POST['address_city'], 
$_POST['quantity'], 
$_POST['payer_email'], 
$_POST['verify_sign'], 
$_POST['last_name'], 
$_POST['address_state'], 
$_POST['txn_id'], 
$_POST['receiver_id'], 
$_POST['item_name'], 
$_POST['item_number'], 
$_POST['payment_gross'], 
$_SESSION['newuser_id'], 
$_SESSION['refer_id'], 
$siteid );
```

Comment: Beware [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com). There is a PHP page there that tells you how to... "replace this sprint crap".

Comment: a php page where?

Comment: At the link I posted, on the left side just after Perl and before PL/SQL.

Comment: ok I looked and don't see any replacement for sprintf? Can you help with my issue?

Comment: Not replacement for sprintf. Replacement for dealing with SQL queries altogether. Any of the described ways are better than what you have (with [PDO])(https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) being my personal favourite).

Comment: ok well I am not a php coder. Just trying to figure out why what I have won't work. I don't know how to test where it keeps failing.